# It feels like a victory to me vs it feels like a victory for me . For me or to me?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, prepositions, for

I was making a post on a forum about how I feel about people from 1999 debuting in the entertainment industry nowadays.

I wanted to express that It felt like a victory to me/for me(because I was born in the same year and a part of me feels reflected on them) . But I don't know if I should use for me or to me.

Answer (score 1):

"To me" just emphasizes that it is a personal opinion. It seemed like they had a victory to you, but other people might see things differently. "For me" means the victory *belongs* to you. You felt like it happened to you. Examples:

```
This is a really big problem to me.
```

In my opinion, it's an important issue that needs to be resolved.

```
This is a really big problem for me.
```

Depending on the context, it could mean that the problem has a large impact on my life personally, or I am the one who must solve it, or maybe it is an unhealthy behavior that I am doing.